# aiohttp : Authorisation denied, ERROR : Not logged in

Tags: python, api, aiohttp

I am currently trying to authorise myself via an HTTP API using aiohttp. However, I am running into some problems.

Docs : https://docs.ftx.com/#overview

The reply I am receiving :

```
 Exception: Not logged in
```

Code:

```
async def test():
    url = 'https://ftx.com/api/account'
    ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
    signature_payload = f'{ts}{"GET"}{url}'
    signature_payload = signature_payload.encode()
    signature =hmac.new("secret_key".encode(),signature_payload,'sha256').hexdigest()

    headers = {'FTX-KEY':'public key',
              'FTX-SIGN':signature,
              'FTX-TS':str(ts)}
    raw = await ClientSession(headers=headers).get(url=url)
    response =await process_response(raw)
    print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(test())
```

EDIT: The specific problem I am having is with authentication. I am currently unable to authorise private requests via this way. A request like GET/markets will result in a dictionary however a request as GET/account_info does not since I need to be authorised via API for this.

Comment: are you able to run the request through postman?

Comment: this question is unfortunately a bit off topic, given it requires knowledge of this particular website api, rather than aiohttp

Comment: Greg, Yes this works, I have made an API wrapper for this platform in the past with the regular Requests package and this seems to work fine

Comment: @UmNyobe, this could well be a mistake by me. I am new to this library, so it is most likely a mistake on my end.